# How can it be done that functions in .so file are automatically exported?

Tags: shared-libraries

In Windows, to call a function in a DLL, the function must have an explicit export declaration. For example, `__declspec(dllexport)` or `.def` file.

Other than Windows, we can call a function in a `.so`(shared object file) even if the function has no export declaration. It is much easier for me to make .so than .dll in terms of this.

Meanwhile, I am curious about how non-Windows enables functions defined in .so be called by other programs without having explicit export declaration. I roughly guess that all of the functions in .so file are automatically exported, but I am not sure of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `.so` file is conventionally a DSO (Dynamic Shared Object, a.k.a shared library) in unix-like OSes. You want to
know how symbols defined in such a file are made visible to the runtime loader
for dynamic linkage of the DSO into the process of some program when
it's executed. That's what you mean by "exported". "Exported" is a somewhat
Windows/DLL-ish term, and is also apt to be confused with "external" or "global",
so we'll say *dynamically visible* instead.

I'll explain how dynamic visibility of symbols can be controlled in the context of
DSOs built with the GNU toolchain - i.e. compiled with a GCC compiler (`gcc`,
`g++`,`gfortran`, etc.) and linked with the binutils linker `ld` (or compatible
alternative compiler and linker). I'll illustrate with C code. The mechanics are
the same for other languages.

The *symbols* defined in an object file are the *file-scope variables* in the C source code. i.e. variables
that are not defined within any block. Block-scope variables:

```
{ int i; ... }
```

are defined only when the enclosing block is being executed and have no permanent
place in an object file.

The symbols defined in an object file generated by GCC are either *local* or *global*.

A local symbol can be referenced within the object file where it's defined but
the object file does not reveal it for linkage *at all*. Not for static linkage.
Not for dynamic linkage. In C, a file-scope variable definition is global
by default and local if it is qualified with the `static` storage class. So
in this source file:

**foobar.c (1)**

```
static int foo(void)
{
    return 42;
}

int bar(void)
{
    return foo();
}
```

`foo` is a local symbol and `bar` is a global one. If we compile this file
with `-save-temps`:

```
$ gcc -save-temps -c -fPIC foobar.c
```

then GCC will save the assembly listing in `foobar.s`, and there we can
see how the generated assembly code registers the fact that `bar` is global and `foo` is not:

**foobar.s (1)**

```
    .file   "foobar.c"
    .text
    .type   foo, @function
foo:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $42, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   foo, .-foo
    .globl  bar
    .type   bar, @function
bar:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    call    foo
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   bar, .-bar
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The assembler directive `.globl bar` means that `bar` is a global symbol.
There is no `.globl foo`; so `foo` is local.

And if we inspect the symbols in the object file itself, with

```
$ readelf -s foobar.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foobar.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     5: 0000000000000000    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 foo
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
     7: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
     8: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
     9: 000000000000000b    11 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 bar
```

the message is the same:

```
     5: 0000000000000000    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 foo
     ...
     9: 000000000000000b    11 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 bar
```

The *global* symbols defined in the object file, and only the global symbols,
are available to the static linker for resolving references in other object files. Indeed
the local symbols only appear in the symbol table of the file at all for possible
use by a debugger or some other object-file probing tool. If we redo the compilation
with even minimal optimisation:

```
$ gcc -save-temps -O1 -c -fPIC foobar.c
$ readelf -s foobar.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 9 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foobar.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
     7: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
     8: 0000000000000000     6 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 bar
```

then `foo` disappears from the symbol table.

Since global symbols are available to the static linker, we can link a program
with `foobar.o` that calls `bar` from another object file:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n",bar());
    return 0;
}
```

Like so:

```
$ gcc -c main.c
$ gcc -o prog main.o foobar.o
$ ./prog
42
```

But as you've noticed, we do not need to change `foobar.o` in any way to make
`bar` dynamically visible to the loader. We can just link it as it is into
a shared library:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so foobar.o
```

then dynamically link the same program with that shared library:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libbar.so
```

and it's fine:

```
$ ./prog
./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libbar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

...Oops. It's fine as long as we let the loader know where `libbar.so` is, since my
working directory here isn't one of the search directories that it caches by default:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
$ ./prog
42
```

The object file `foobar.o` has a table of symbols as we've seen,
in the `.symtab` section, including (at least) the global symbols that are available to the static linker.
The DSO `libbar.so` has a symbol table in its `.symtab` section too. But it also has a *dynamic* symbol table,
in it's `.dynsym` section:

```
$ readelf -s libbar.so

    Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 6 entries:
       Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
         0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
         1: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize
         2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
         3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
         4: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
         5: 00000000000010f5     6 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 bar

    Symbol table '.symtab' contains 45 entries:
       Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
         0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
         ...
         ...
        21: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
        22: 0000000000001040     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 deregister_tm_clones
        23: 0000000000001070     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 register_tm_clones
        24: 00000000000010b0     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 __do_global_dtors_aux
        25: 0000000000004020     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   19 completed.7930
        26: 0000000000003e88     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 __do_global_dtors_aux_fin
        27: 00000000000010f0     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 frame_dummy
        28: 0000000000003e80     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 __frame_dummy_init_array_
        29: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foobar.c
        30: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
        31: 0000000000002094     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 __FRAME_END__
        32: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS
        33: 0000000000003e90     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 _DYNAMIC
        34: 0000000000004020     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 __TMC_END__
        35: 0000000000004018     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 __dso_handle
        36: 0000000000001000     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 _init
        37: 0000000000002000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
        38: 00000000000010fc     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   10 _fini
        39: 0000000000004000     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
        40: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize
        41: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
        42: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
        43: 00000000000010f5     6 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 bar
```

The symbols in the dynamic symbol table are the ones that are *dynamically* visible -
available to the runtime loader. You
can see that `bar` appears *both* in the `.symtab` and in the `.dynsym` of `libbar.so`.
In both cases, the symbol has `GLOBAL` in the `bind` ( = *binding*)
column and `DEFAULT` in the `vis` ( = *visibility*) column.

If you want `readelf` to show you *just* the dynamic symbol table, then:

```
readelf --dyn-syms libbar.so
```

will do it, but not for `foobar.o`, because an object file has *no* dynamic symbol table:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms foobar.o; echo Done
Done
```

So the linkage:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so foobar.o
```

*creates* the dynamic symbol table of `libbar.so`, and populates it with symbols
the from *global* symbol table of `foobar.o` (and various GCC boilerplate
files that GCC adds to the linkage by defauilt).

This makes it look like your guess:

> I roughly guess that all of the functions in .so file are automatically exported

is right. In fact it's close, but not correct.

See what happens if I recompile `foobar.c`
like this:

```
$ gcc -save-temps -fvisibility=hidden -c -fPIC foobar.c
```

Let's take another look at the assembly listing:

**foobar.s (2)**

```
...
...
    .globl  bar
    .hidden bar
    .type   bar, @function
bar:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    call    foo
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
...
...
```

Notice the assembler directive:

```
    .hidden bar
```

that wasn't there before. `.globl   bar` is still there; `bar` is still a global
symbol. I can still statically link `foobar.o` in this program:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o foobar.o
$ ./prog
42
```

And I can still link this shared library:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so foobar.o
```

But I can no longer dynamically link this program:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libbar.so
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `bar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In `foobar.o`, `bar` is still in the symbol table:

```
$ readelf -s foobar.o | grep bar
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foobar.c
     9: 000000000000000b    11 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 bar
```

but it is now marked `HIDDEN` in the `vis` ( = `visibility`) column of the output.

And `bar` is still in the symbol table of `libbar.so`:

```
$ readelf -s libbar.so | grep bar
    29: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foobar.c
    41: 0000000000001100    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 bar
```

But this time, it is a `LOCAL` symbol. It will *not* be available to the static
linker from `libbar.so` - as we saw just now when our linkage failed. And it is no longer in the
dynamic symbol table at all:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms libbar.so | grep bar; echo done
done
```

So the effect of `-fvisibility=hidden`, when compiling `foobar.c`, is to make
the compiler annotate `.globl` symbols as `.hidden` in `foobar.o`. Then, when
`foobar.o` is linked into `libbar.so`, the linker converts every global *hidden*
symbol to a *local* symbol in `libbar.so`, so that it cannot be used to resolve references
whenever `libbar.so` is linked with something else. And it does *not* add the hidden
symbols to the *dynamic* symbol table of `libbar.so`, so the runtime loader cannot
see them to resolve references dynamically.

*The story so far:* When the linker creates a shared library, it adds to the dynamic
symbol table all of the global symbols that are defined in the input object files and are not marked *hidden*
by the compiler. These become the dynamically visible symbols of the shared library. Global symbols are not
hidden by default, but we can hide them with the compiler option `-fvisibility=hidden`. The *visibility*
that this option refers to is *dynamic* visibility.

Now the ability to remove global symbols from dynamic visibility with `-fvisibility=hidden`
doesn't look very useful yet, because it seems that any object file we compile with
that option can contribute no dynamically visible symbols to a shared library.

But actually, we can control *individually* which global symbols defined in an object file
will be dynamically visible and which will not. Let's change `foobar.c` as follows:

**foobar.c (2)**

```
static int foo(void)
{
    return 42;
}

int __attribute__((visibility("default"))) bar(void)
{
    return foo();
}
```

The [`__attribute__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) syntax you see here is a GCC language extension
that is used to specify properties of symbols that are not expressible in the standard language - such as dynamic visibility. Microsoft's
`declspec(dllexport)` is an Microsoft language extension with the same effect as GCC's `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`,
But for GCC, global symbols defined in an object file will possess `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` *by default*, and you
have to compile with `-fvisibility=hidden` to override that.

Recompile like last time:

```
$ gcc -fvisibility=hidden -c -fPIC foobar.c
```

And now the symbol table of `foobar.o`:

```
$ readelf -s foobar.o | grep bar
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foobar.c
     9: 000000000000000b    11 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 bar
```

shows `bar` with `DEFAULT` visibility once again, despite `-fvisibility=hidden`.  And if we relink `libbar.so`:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so foobar.o
```

we see that `bar` is back in the dynamic symbol table:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms libbar.so | grep bar
     5: 0000000000001100    11 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 bar
```

So, `-fvisibility=hidden` tells the compiler to mark a global symbol as hidden
*unless*, in the source code, we explicitly specify a countervailing dynamic visibility
for that symbol.

That's one way to select precisely the symbols from an object file that we wish
to make dynamically visible: pass `-fvisibility=hidden` to the compiler, and
individually specify `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`, in the source code, for just
the symbols we want to be dynamically visible.

Another way is *not* to pass `-fvisibility=hidden` to the compiler, and indvidually
specify `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`, in the source code, for just the
symbols that we *don't* want to be dynamically visible. So if we change `foobar.c` again
like so:

**foobar.c (3)**

```
static int foo(void)
{
    return 42;
}

int __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) bar(void)
{
    return foo();
}
```

then recompile with default visibility:

```
$ gcc -c -fPIC foobar.c
```

`bar` reverts to *hidden* in the object file:

```
$ readelf -s foobar.o | grep bar
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foobar.c
     9: 000000000000000b    11 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 bar
```

And after relinking `libbar.so`, `bar` is again absent from its dynamic symbol
table:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so foobar.o
$ readelf --dyn-syms libbar.so | grep bar; echo Done
Done
```

The professional approach is to minimize the dynamic API of
a DSO to exactly what is specified. With the apparatus we've discussed,
that means compiling with `-fvisibility=hidden` and using `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` to
expose the specified API. A dynamic API can also be controlled - and *versioned* - with the GNU linker
using a type of linker script called a [*version-script*](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html): that is a
yet more professional approach.

Further reading:

- [GCC Wiki: Visibility](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html)
- [GCC Manual: Common Function Attributes -> `visibility ("visibility_type")`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)